# firefox_addons query on Osquery

Tags: osquery

When I input below command in osquery, nothing comes up. But I have firefox installed with bunch of addons. I am using Windows 11. I tried with administrator privilege but it's not working.

```
 SELECT * FROM firefox_addons;
```

I have also used the command in documentation [osquery firefox_addon github](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/blob/master/specs/firefox_addons.table)

```
SELECT * FROM users CROSS JOIN firefox_addons USING (uid);
```